# Why doesn't an alert message show when I enter the wrong word?

Tags: javascript, html

This form should show a error message when I enter more than 8 characters and the characters are not all numbers. Why doesn't it work?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <input type="text" id="username">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
    function validateForm(){
        var x = document.getElementById("username");
        if(x.match(/^[0-9]{8,}$/))
            return true;
        else{
            alert("MESSAGE");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you want the '.value` of the element?

Comment: @JonK - thks - never saw it. Let's delete all related comments as no longer relavent.

Comment: Does it work with `document.getElementById("username").value` now? You shouldn’t edit your question to replace the broken code by working code, otherwise this invalidates all answers and the question becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect it should be `x.value.match`, `x` is the object, `x.value` is the value

Answer (score 1):

DOM elements do not have a `.match()` method.  You probably want to get `.value`, which is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var x = document.getElementById("username");
```

To

```
var x = document.getElementById("username").value;
```